# Printing a each string of an array vs Printing each character of every string of an array

Tags: c

I want to make a tabular 2D array filled with  characters to be able to put a  character in a specified [y][x] location.

```
int main() {
    int DIMENSION[2] = { 5, 5 };
    
    //create buffer [multidimensional array]
    char buffer[DIMENSION[1]][DIMENSION[0]];
    int x, y;

    // fill buffer
    for (y = 0; y < DIMENSION[1]; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < DIMENSION[1]; x++){
            printf("%d%d\n", y, x);
            buffer[y][x] = 'o';
        }
    }

    // manipulate the buffer here


    // draw the buffer
    for (int i = -1; i < DIMENSION[1]; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", buffer[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the output of this is:

```
ooooooooooooooooooooooooo
oooooooooooooooooooo
ooooooooooooooo
oooooooooo
ooooo
```

code only works if the draw method is:

```
    for (y = 0; y < DIMENSION[1]; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < DIMENSION[1]; x++) {
            printf("%c", buffer[y][x]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

In this case, it prints out:

```
ooooo
ooooo
ooooo
ooooo
ooooo
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: `y<DIMENSION[1]` *and* `x<DIMENSION[1]`? Are you sure about that? What happens if the dimensions are different?

Comment: As for your problem, you have a fatal flaw in that you forget that strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** string*. You never null-terminate your strings. You can't pass them to any function expecting a null-terminated string.

Comment: @Lundin: I reopened the question  because the one you linked it to was too general and its accepted answer did not provide an easy solution for the OP in the context of a 2D array.

Comment: Ohh I always wondered what the difference is between ```char string[] = "abcd";``` and ```char string[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};```

Comment: Question: does the '\0' count as an element? Or does it not allocate space for it since it's null therefore making making it inaccessible when indexing an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has undefined behavior because none of the pointers passed to `printf` in `printf("%s\n", buffer[i]);` are null terminated strings.  You should either:

- add an extra column to the `buffer` matrix and set its elements to `'\0'`, or
- pass an extra *precision* argument to limit the number of characters to print to `DIMENSION[0]`:

  ```
   printf("%.*s\n", DIMENSION[0], buffer[i]);
  ```

Also note that the inner initialization loop should use `DIMENSION[0]` instead of `DIMENSION[1]`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int DIMENSION[2] = { 5, 5 };
    
    //create buffer [multidimensional array]
    char buffer[DIMENSION[1]][DIMENSION[0]];

    // fill buffer
    for (int y = 0; y < DIMENSION[1]; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < DIMENSION[0]; x++) {
            //printf("%d%d\n", y, x);
            buffer[y][x] = 'o';
        }
    }

    // manipulate the buffer here
    // [...]

    // draw the buffer
    for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION[1]; i++) {
        printf("%.*s\n", DIMENSION[0], buffer[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: there's only one format specifier but you're supplying it with 2 variables. teach me sensei

Comment: oh sorry didn't read your notes. So it was a length argument?

Comment: @Suikyoo: actually it is a *precision* argument for the `%.*s` conversion.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int main(){
    int DIMENSION[2] = {5, 5};
    
    //create buffer [multidimensional array]
    //allocate space for another element per char array
    char buffer[DIMENSION[1]][DIMENSION[0] + 1];
    int x, y;
    //fill buffer
    for (y=0; y<DIMENSION[1]; y++){
        for (x=0; x<DIMENSION[0]; x++){
            buffer[y][x] = 'o';

        }
        //after looping through every displayable char in each string,
        //add a null-terminating character at the last slot allocation
        buffer[y][DIMENSION[0]] = '\0';
    }

    //manipulate the buffer here


    //draw the buffer
    for (int i=0; i<DIMENSION[1];i++){
        printf("%s\n", buffer[i]);

    }
   
    return 0;
}
```

eyyyy how we lookin bois?
Added a null terminating character at the end of every char array element in the array. Now printf() can finally stop being sensitive af (Pfft it's just a null terminating character. Not like you can find the length of the string through that or anything).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int DIMENSION[2] = { 5, 5 };

```
//create buffer [multidimensional array]
char buffer[DIMENSION[1]][DIMENSION[0]];
int x, y;

// fill buffer
for (y = 0; y < DIMENSION[1]; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < DIMENSION[1]; x++)
    {
        buffer[y][x] = 'o';
    }
}

// manipulate the buffer here


// draw the buffer
for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION[1]; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < DIMENSION[0]; j++)
    {
        printf("%c" , buffer[i][j]);       
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
```

}